# qmicli Cannot set expected data format

Tags: networking, ip, network-interface, modem

OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Kernel: Linux 4.9.41-v7+

I am using a EM7430 embedded modem.  This modem supports raw-ip only.

Run

```
ip addr
```

shows

```
3: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 22:fb:ec:ed:05:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wwan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 22:fb:ec:ed:05:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Run

```
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --wda-get-data-format
```

shows

```
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] Successfully got data format
                   QoS flow header: no
               Link layer protocol: 'raw-ip'
  Uplink data aggregation protocol: 'disabled'
Downlink data aggregation protocol: 'disabled'
                     NDP signature: '0'
  Uplink data aggregation max size: '0'
Downlink data aggregation max size: '0'
```

Run

```
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --set-expected-data-format=raw-ip
```

shows

```
error: cannot set expected data format: Expected data format not updated properly to 'raw-ip': got '802-3' instead
```

Since the EM7430 supports only raw-ip, I cannot use dhcp to get the IP address.  I have to configure this manually.

I am stuck on setting the expected data format to raw-ip.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Just a silly mistake, I forgot to take the interface down before I execute the command to set the expected format to raw-ip.

Comment: Thanks! I just made the same mistake